# Hyphen in a sql select statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql

This is my very simple select statement:

`select * from ProductDimensions where Item='100-1000'`

When entered into SSMS it queries fine and returns the results. When run through my program in VS it returns nothing. An item without a hyphen returns fine. Is there some special syntax required for this to work from my C# code?

The C# code:

```
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ProductDimensions where Item='100-1000'", conn);
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
```

Like I said if I put in a number with no hyphen, such as '1000' it works fine.

Comment: Is Item a varchar column or an int column?

Comment: It might not hurt to try using string literals in your C# code by prefixing your strings with the @ character.

Comment: @Andrew I gave it a shot, but no luck there either.

Comment: @Nick did you get it working in the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a parameterised SQL string instead and you'll avoid issues like this, as well as others like SQL injection:

```
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ProductDimensions where Item=@Item";
adapter.Parameters.Add("@Item", SqlDbType.NChar, 15, "100-1000");
```

(You may have to adjust the `SqlDbType` and length)

Comment: For the last hour I have tried this code and every permutation of it that I could come up with. Same results hyphenated numbers don't work, non-hyphenated do. I have tried changing the data type of the column to char, varchar, and nvarchar all with no luck. At this point I want to scream.

Comment: @Nick What kind of data is in this column you're filtering on? Is is just plain text? You're not trying to filter on a range are you?

Comment: It's varchar, I am not filtering on a range it is just a part number with a hyphen in it.

Comment: I rebuilt my table and it works now. If anyone can tell me what could have caused that, that would be great. Thanks w69rdy for your efforts.

Comment: Are you removing the ' that you had around the original string? What happens if you change it to a LIKE instead of a =? There may be blank spaces either side, have you checked for that?

Comment: Yeah I had tried like and tried it with and without the single quotes.

Comment: And does it find it if you remove the hyphen? I wonder if it's ignoring it for some reason..